# Significato di "serrar sotto" in questo contesto

Tags: meaning, verbs

Nel racconto *Un giorno di fuoco*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Perché Gallesio desse fondo alle sue munizioni, i carabinieri avevano studiato di alzare allo scoperto i loro berretti in punta a dei bastoni, e sulle prime Gallesio c’era cascato e non ne perdonava uno, ma poi aveva capito il trucco e risparmiava i colpi, ciononostante i carabinieri non riuscivano a **serrar sotto** di quel tanto che permettesse il lancio delle bombe lacrimogene.

Malgrado aver cercato il verbo "serrare" in alcuni dizionari, non riesco a capire a quale accezione corrisponda l'espressione  "serrar sotto" che appare in questo passaggio. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Comment: In gergo militare, *serrare* significa *avvicinarsi*, *chiudere*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nel contesto da te citato ***serrar sotto*** significa avvicinarsi.

Su Treccani per [serrare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/serrare/) puoi trovare:

> 1c. Premere, incalzare: *s. il nemico*.

Sempre su Treccani per [sotto](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sotto/) puoi trovare l'espressione simile ***farsi sotto***:

> 4b. *farsi sotto*, avvicinarsi a poco a poco, per lo più con intenzione
>   ostile, quindi anche attaccare l’avversario con prudenza ma
>   decisamente (come comando: *fatevi sotto!*; o assol., *sotto!*);

Nel libro [*Guerra in camicia nera* di Giuseppe Berto](https://books.google.it/books?id=Ufs-PIrupCAC&pg=PT68&lpg=PT68&dq=serrar%20sotto&source=bl&ots=vyoJhbWu9M&sig=waFe8hiB_GGCEYl-k3YoOZdjNFg&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiX5-_fnPvcAhUhMuwKHTYMDOgQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=serrar%20sotto&f=false) si può trovare l'espressione con un significato simile a quello del contesto da te citato:

> Dovendo sistemarci a caposaldo, abbiamo cominciato a scavare buche e
>   postazioni.  Lavoro, questa volta, ancor più sgradito, in quanto che
>   ci eravamo illusi di trovar qui fortini e alloggi pronti.  Ad ogni
>   modo, potremo fare le cose con accuratezza e calma, dato che gli
>   inglesi impiegheranno diverso tempo prima di **serrar sotto**. A
>   quest'attacco si dovranno preparare con grande cautela.

Comment: Quindi si tratta di "avvicinarsi" ma con la sfumatura di  "premere, incalzare".

Comment: Esattamente, stavano a distanza di sicurezza ma comunque determinati a stanarlo. Nonostante Gallesio avesse ridotto il volume di fuoco per risparmiare munizioni, i Carabinieri non riuscivano ad avvicinarsi abbastanza per lanciare le bombe lacrimogene.